# Java validating an IP address and subnet

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment where I have to assign IP addresses, subnet mask, default gateway, and dns and validate them.

I have got the IP address validator method ensuring that there are 3 dots (4 octets), and that the numbers are in valid range (1-255) by using string split.

I am now trying to figure out how I can ensure that it is an assignable address (I.E. if its a class A address, make sure that it isn't `124.0.0.0` etc.) Same for the subnet mask, I need to check the parts and see if they are `255.0.0.0` or `255.255.255.0`.

I have also looked into string tokenizers and have one where it goes through a while loop and while the string has more elements, I can print each one to the screen using `.` as a delim, but I am not sure how to store the information so I can later compare the values (in if statements?)

Sorry I am still pretty new to programming and hope you understand. Thanks for any help!

Comment: An IP address is just a 32 bit integer and can be stored as such. It would then let you do masking and testing with bitwise operations. Look up what rules govern which IP addresses are valid and test for each of them.

Comment: First - validate an IP using regular expression. Next - convert all 4 numbers(given as strings) to numbers and use bitwise operation and alike to verify the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex

public abstract class CommonBase {
    private final static Long[] SUBNET_MASK = new Long[]{4294934528L, 4294950912L, 4294959104L, 4294963200L, 4294965248L, 4294966272L, 4294966784L, 4294967040L, 4294967168L, 4294967232L, 4294967264L, 4294967280L, 4294967288L, 4294967292L, 4294967294L, 4294967295L};

    public static boolean isValidIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        if (ipAddress != null) {
            Matcher matcher = Patterns.IP_ADDRESS.matcher(ipAddress);
            if (matcher != null) {
                return matcher.matches();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static long ipAddressToLong(String ipAddress) {
        if (ipAddress != null) {
            String[] s = ipAddress.split("\\.");
            if (s != null && s.length == 4) {
                long result = 0;
                for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
                    try {
                        long n = Long.parseLong(s[3 - i]);
                        result |= n << (i * 8);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean isValidSubnetMask(String subnetMask) {
        if (subnetMask != null) {
            long lSubnetMask = ipAddressToLong(subnetMask);
            if (lSubnetMask > 0) {
                return Arrays.asList(SUBNET_MASK).contains(lSubnetMask);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to use the above code:

```
CommonBase.isValidIpAddress("192.168.0.1"); // true
CommonBase.isValidSubnetMask("255.255.255.0"); // true
```

Comment: Just dropping code isn't that helpful; especially as there isnt even a main() to run that would show how to properly use these methods. Could be a nice answer, if you spent some more time explaining it.